# IIS 7 unable to render page with response.buffer = false

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, iis-7

I have an ASP app that is hosted on Windows Server 2008 R2. I was told to create an new site for testing purpose on another Windows 2008 R2 server.
After the test site comes up, I find many pages are showing some garbage while others still work as normal as the production site. I found these failed to display pages (even some have no data to load) contain this line:

```
<% Response.Buffer = False %>
```

Setting Buffer = True fix the display problem. Obviously, it seems some setting in the IIS of the test server that are differed from the production server. Do you know what that is? I don't want to mess with hundreds of pages of legacy codes.

Thanks